# Laravel Sub-domain routing and resource controllers

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain

Here is my route:

```
Route::group(array('domain'=>'{subdomain}.example.com'), function()  
{
    Route::group(array('before'=>array('authenticate')), function()
    {
        Route::resource('post', 'PostController');

        Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');

        Route::resource('forum', 'ForumController');

        Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

    });
});
```

It seems that by default ALL my resource controllers are now taking the subdomain as first parameter and I can't find a way to change it.

If possible, I'd like to ignore the subdomain entirely.

Example use cases:

admin.example.com/forum/1?domain=foo

foo.example.com/forum/1

bar.example.com/forum/2

This site hosts 2 forums, but there is only 1 admin managing all of them. For admin to access the forum foo, admin must also supply domain=foo to look at it.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your routes file? I dont see any other resource controllers other than PostController?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I've added all of them in

Comment: `Route::group(array('domain'=>'admin.example.com')` you can use the rule for admin separately before `oute::group(array('domain'=>'{subdomain}.example.com')` rule.

Comment: @AmitGarg yes, but it seems quite ugly if I have to copy all those resource controllers again for each of those route domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you dont want to **route** based on the subdomain, then you should only **filter** the subdomain for access.

```
Route::filter('subdomain', function($route, $request) 
{
    $host = $request->getHost();
    $parts = explode('.', $host);
    $subdomain = $parts[0];

    if ($subdomain == 'something')
    {
         // Allow or deny
    }
});


Route::group(array('before'=>array('subdomain|authenticate')), function()
    {
        Route::resource('post', 'PostController');

        Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');

        Route::resource('forum', 'ForumController');

        Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

    });
```

Comment: I might not be clear enough. I need to use subdomains for all routes because both normal users and admins will be accessing the same routes. But the subdomain parameter is not important to the functions at all, they just trigger different authentication.

Comment: Yeah - sorry your not being clear enough to me - I dont understand. Can you please provide some further examples in your question to expand more.

Comment: oh wait - i get it now - give me 2 mins - i'll change my answer

Comment: I've added example use cases in the original question. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Try that - see if it helps.

Comment: @Laurence Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594340/how-can-i-implement-resource-controllers-if-i-use-many-get-on-the-laravel